# Countdown It does not Work on a minute system

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple code but there is a problem
How do I make this code work in a minute and a second system
Tried but only work a second!

You can look at the code
https://jsfiddle.net/o183pdqg/1/

I hope for help because I am really tired and I am looking for a solution

```js
function secondPassed() {
  var seconds = 120;
  var countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown');
  var contentElement = document.getElementById('content');
  var adsElement = document.getElementById('ads');
  var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);
  var remainingSeconds = seconds;
  if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
  }

  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }


  adsElement.style.display = '';
  countdownElement.innerHTML = remainingSeconds;

  var interval = setInterval(function() {

    countdownElement.innerHTML = --remainingSeconds;

    if (remainingSeconds === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      contentElement.style.display = '';
      adsElement.style.display = 'none';
    }

  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="#container" onclick="secondPassed()">Send Code</a>
  <div id="ads" style="display: none">
    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <div>Sent!</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="display: none">Error!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So instead of "120" seconds you want to display say "2:00"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put variable `minutes` and `seconds` within `setInterval` function to make it work. Convert the time `var remainingSeconds = seconds * 1000;` from second to milisecond so it will make it easier when working with `new Date().getTime()`.

To get minutes and second, try it using `modulus (%)` operator to get remaining time from your starting time.

```js
var availability = true
function secondPassed() {
  if (!availability) {
    return false
  }
  var seconds = 120;
      var countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown');
      var contentElement = document.getElementById('content');
      var adsElement = document.getElementById('ads');

  availability = false
  adsElement.style.display = '';
  contentElement.style.display = 'none';
  
  
  function runInterval () {
    
      var remainingSeconds = seconds * 1000;
     let minutes = Math.floor(remainingSeconds % (1000*60*60)/ (1000*60));
    let seconds1 = Math.floor(remainingSeconds % (1000*60) / 1000);
      if (seconds1 < 10) {
        seconds1 = "0" + seconds1;
      }

      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds1;
      if (seconds == 0) {
//         clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "";
      } else {
        seconds--;
      }
    if (remainingSeconds === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      contentElement.style.display = '';
      adsElement.style.display = 'none';
      availability = true
    }
  }

  var interval = setInterval(function() {

//     countdownElement.innerHTML = --remainingSeconds;
    runInterval ()
    

  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <a href="#container" onclick="secondPassed()">Send Code</a>
  <div id="ads" style="display: none">
    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <div>Sent!</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="display: none">Error!</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question how can I remove Element Error! Message after Click the Send button again

Comment: @Nikola just add `contentElement.style.display = 'none';` before `runInterval()`, check my edit

Comment: Bro There is a problem, with the code when pressing to send code more than once same time, working timing irregularly please check it

Comment: check again, I added `var availability = true`, when send code is clicked `availability` is set to `false`, when time is out `availability` is set to `true` again

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this answer

```
secondPassed = () => {

    let remainingSeconds = 120;
    const countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown');
    const contentElement = document.getElementById('content');
    const adsElement = document.getElementById('ads');
    adsElement.style.display = '';

    const getPad = (num) => {
        return (num < 10) ? '0' + num.toString() : num.toString();
    }

    const interval = setInterval(() => {

        let minutes = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 60) % 60;
        let seconds = getPad(remainingSeconds % 60);
        countdownElement.innerHTML = `${minutes} : ${seconds}`;
        remainingSeconds--;

        if (remainingSeconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            contentElement.style.display = '';
            adsElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```